# Calling onClick without clicking

Tags: java, android

Do you know how to call the `onClick` method assigned to a button in the XML layout file without clicking the button? I've tried the `performClick` method already.

```
@Override
  public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      Button signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
      try {
        signUpButton.performClick();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: We can't answer a question like that without seeing your code and exactly what happens when you say "it doesn't work."  You give us nothing to reply to.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1. Extract code performed in `onClick` to a method

Step 2. Call this method in place of `button.performClick()`

Answer (score 0):

try `callOnClick`:

```
findViewById(R.id.hello).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
findViewById(R.id.hello).callOnClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know how to call the onClick method assigned to a button in the XML layout file **without clicking the button?**

You can call a function for when the user clicks the button and call that function independently.

```
@Override
  public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      OnbuttonPressed();
    }
    return false;
  }

....
public void OnbuttonPressed(){
    Button signUpButton = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
      try {
        signUpButton.performClick();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then you can call the function "OnbuttonPressed()" anywhere else.